# Вывод 4-х значных комбинаций

Tags: php

Пытаюсь реализовать вывод **4-х** значных значений имея набор символов :

```
$a = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
```

Так как тут **36 символов**, а знаков **4**, то комбинаций должно выйти **1679616** (`36^4` степени)
Мне нужно в таком формате:

```
1111
1112
1113
....
111z // Далее, после 111z идет: 1121
1121
1122
1123
....
112z
```

и так далее...
Как написать подобный функционал?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать свою реализацию счётчика с переносом: символ в последнем разряде заменяется на последующий, пока это возможно.  Если символ 'z' (или индекс 35), то он сбрасывается в '1' (или индекс 0) и инкрементируется второй справа символ (если возможно, иначе сбрасываем разряд и идём дальше и т.д.).

Можно и просто сделать цикл от 0 до 1679615 и представлять счётчик цикла в 36-разрядной системе счисления.

Answer (score 0):

Нууууу.... Как вариант, а там может быть кто-то и годнее предложит. Оптимизацией займетесь сами если она вам нужна.

```
function gen_comb(&$last_key, &$alphabet = array(), $a = 0, $b = 0, $c = 0, $d = 0) {
    $GEN = array($a,$b,$c,$d);

    //  RETURN
    var_dump($alphabet[$GEN[0]].$alphabet[$GEN[1]].$alphabet[$GEN[2]].$alphabet[$GEN[3]]);

    //  NEW
    $GEN[3]++;
    for ($i=3; $i >= 1; $i--) { 
        if ($GEN[$i] > $last_key) {
            $GEN[$i] = 0;
            $GEN[$i-1]++;
        }
    }

    //  REPEAT?
    if ($GEN[0] > $last_key) {
        return;
    }else{
        gen_comb($last_key, $alphabet, $GEN[0], $GEN[1], $GEN[2], $GEN[3]);
    }
}

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
end($array);

gen_comb(key($array), $array);
```